# Provide an example of a bounded subset of $\Bbb R$ that does not have a supremum.

Tags: real-analysis

Must be a subset of the real numbers. 
Must be bounded.
Has no least upper bound (not that it has no least upper bound in the set, but that it has no least upper bound at all)

Comment: The empty set?  Otherwise it isn't possible.

Comment: Oops, I accidentally clicked the rollback button.

Answer (score 1):

Your question contradicts the [Completeness of the real numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers) and as mentioned by Hagen the answer is just the empty set.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers#Least_upper_bound_property

Answer (score 0):

The set $\emptyset$ is bounded, for example all its elements are $<42$. Yet there is no least upper bound: Whenever $M$ is an upper bound then so is $M-1$.

Comment: Is the empty set a subset of R?

Comment: The empty set is a subset of *anything*.

Comment: Since each of its elements is a real number ...